# Change Title TextView when call one fragment to another fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation

I am working on the application in which I added  a Navigation Drawer with Tabs. So, for the Navigation Drawer menu option I create a fragment for each option and it works well...

In my main Activity I inflate my `TabFragment` (contains fragment_1, or fragment_2) as `UI`, and on the Fragment_1 there is one Button and when I click the button I want to open the Navigation Drawer fragment....

My Navigation Drawer fragment opens fine, but the problem is when my Navigation drawer fragment is open my `titleBar` doesn't change as per the fragment title...

**Note:** I know when we open a fragment we have to replace the fragment View to the new fragment View but I want to open a Fragment as an Activity

[image]

Picture1: When I click on `Button` the Second Picture appears, but I want to change the `TitleView` and remove the `Navigation drawer` icon.
[image]

### Edit

In my MainActivity, I inflate Tabfragment as

```
mFragmentTransaction=mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new TabFragment()).commit();
```

MyTabFragment :

```
public class TabFragment extends Fragment {

    public TabFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    public static TabLayout tabLayout;
    public static ViewPager viewPager;
    public static int int_items = 2 ;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View x=inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main_menu,null);
        tabLayout=(TabLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager =(ViewPager) x.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
        tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
            }
        });
        return x;
    }

    class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    return new HomeFragment();
                case 1:
                    return new Offers();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return int_items;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0 :
                    return "Home";
                case 1:
                    return "Offers";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

On Button click in `HomeFragment`(or fragment_1)

```
Fragment fragment = new NavigationDrawerFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: provide your code, so that someone can help.

Comment: check updated question please'

Answer (score 0):

I just find my Question's Answer..

Before i tried to call fragment to fragment class that's why my ContainerView Remains same in the NavigationDrawer Fragment. So Now this time, I am Creating a new Activity and in this Activity I inflate the navigation Drawer fragment, due to this my previous ContainerView is Replaced by the New Activity layout